# converting a ShaderToy in to Webgl shader for the Three js ( need help )

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, shader, fragment-shader

Can you help me pls to translate this shader into three js!

[this shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MdKXDm)

it tried in this way and just get a white screen!

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

#define F length(.5-fract(gl_FragColor.xyw*=mat3(-2,-1,2, 3,-2,1, 1,2,2)*

uniform vec2 u_resolution;

void main() {
    vec2 p = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution.xy;
    gl_FragColor.xy = p*(gl_FragColor.w+.2)*.1;
    gl_FragColor = pow(min(min(F.5)),F.4))),F.3))), 7.)*25.+vec4(0,.35,.5,1);
}
```

pls try with this editor :

https://thebookofshaders.com/edit.php?log=180503054204

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow! Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What do you pass for u_resolution, where is the rest of the code `THREE.ShaderMaterial` etc.

Comment: `gl_FragColor.w` what do you expect this to be? try putting 0.5 instead of that

Comment: or actually `gl_FragColor.w = 0.5;` above `vec2 p`

Comment: @pailhead actually, for now, I try to implement thing via this editor :
http://thebookofshaders.com/edit.php?log=180503053430

Comment: `gl_FragColor` is empty at first, and i'm not actually sure what `.w` will yield. Since you do set `.xy` you might as well set `.w` to something

Comment: with u_time I will get this error  https://thebookofshaders.com/edit.php?log=180503054204

Answer (score 0):

Oh! Thanks [@pailhead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2548153/pailhead)... yeah, you are right about the set the gl_FragColor at first!

it solved my issue.

Thanks for your Help =)